# Trying to find a good plugin or a way to add counter//share buttons to posts(in search or category page or homepage)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, twitter, facebook-like, social-networking

I am trying to find a good (wp)plugin or a code to add social share/counter buttons under my posts.

I've tried many of them so far none of them had fb,twitter,google+,linkedin which worked properly.

The closes i had was a plugin that have everything aligned correctly, have all the buttons. but when you click on FB(which is the main one IMO) the window that opens being cut and you cant enter the share details.

I am trying to do something like: `http://www.mindtickle.com/blog/`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) service? I'm using that for my blog and I have no complaints.

It is very flexible since you can customize which buttons to show.

It also comes with analytics, so you can analyze visitor interactions, their shares,...